# Django raise BadRequestError(msg) razorpay.errors.BadRequestError: The amount must be an integer. while refund

Tags: python, django, integer, razorpay

When I try to print it, it appears as an integer, but I get an error saying "The amount must be an integer." when I run the project

[image]

```
if str(Payments).__contains__("pay"):
    paymentId = Payments.payment_id
    amount = int(Payments.amount_paid)
    refund_amount = int(amount) * 100
    reamount = int(refund_amount)
    print(reamount)
    print(type(reamount))

    client = razorpay.Client(auth=(settings.RAZOR_KEY_ID, settings.RAZOR_KEY_SECRET))

    client.payment.refund(
        paymentId,
        {
            "amount": reamount,
            "speed": "optimum",
        },
    )

    # addning stock in product
    order_items = OrderProduct.objects.filter(order=order)
    for item in order_items:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=item.product_id)
        product.stock += item.quantity
        product.save()
```

[image]

Comment: This may [help](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-python/blob/bd024a63f53f23b506b1851fe7d4241dd7f767e1/razorpay/resources/payment.py#L52) you

Answer (score 0):

I've just changed the dict type to direct parameter passing

```
#refund process of stripe
if str(Payments).__contains__("pay"):
    paymentId     = Payments.payment_id
    refund_amount = Payments.amount_paid
    amount        = int(refund_amount * 100)

    
    client = razorpay.Client(auth=(settings.RAZOR_KEY_ID, settings.RAZOR_KEY_SECRET))
    print(paymentId)
    client.payment.refund( paymentId,amount,)

    #addning stock in product
    order_items = OrderProduct.objects.filter(order=order)
    for item in order_items:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=item.product_id)
        product.stock += item.quantity
        product.save()
```

Then its works

[image]

[image]